# SubSonic 3 Installation Doesn't Work?

Tags: asp.net, subsonic, subsonic3

Ok I have following the tutorial here as best I can

http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Setting_up_SubSonic_3.0

As the files you get in the download are nothing like what is shown in the video??  So I am literally just guessing which files to use??

Then I drag the files / folders into Visual studio (As the video shows) and NOTHING happens??  It just adds the files to my solution?? Or adds the folders to my solution as normal files... Nothing gets executed as shown in the video??

I realise Rob has spent a lot of time on this off his own back, and I am trying not to be a whining old women BUT... How are we expected to use it, if the installation video is completely different to the actual files you get in the download AND when you drag the files into VS2008 nothing happens - Which is completely different to the video?  My VS does not recognise TT files as being anything special...

I really want to use this new version, as I loved v2.1 but I'm loosing faith

**RANT OVER**

Answer (score 3):

OK a few places to start:

1. Are you using Visual Studio Express, if so unfortunately it doesn't support t4 and so won't work with SubSonic 3
2. Try right clicking on the tt files and clicking 'Run Custom Tool'
3. If your project is a Website rather than a Web Application Project t4 won't work and you won't see 'Run Custom Tool' in the right click menu. In this case either convert the project or you can use a separate class library project in your solution and add the templates to it, then reference this in your website.
4. Choose whether you want to use Simple, Linq or ActiveRecord templates. Have a look [here](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Selecting_Templates) to help you choose (you can always change your mind later)
5. Watch the video for whichever template you've chosen, the setup video you linked to is unfortunately a little dated and I think the template specific ones are much more helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I want to try an use the SimpleRepos but I open up the download and in the T4 folders are the following folders?

-Active Record
-LinqTemplates
-Subsonic.TemplatesVB
-TemplateProviders

Sorry to be dumb? But where are the simplerepo templates?

Comment: There are no SimpeRepository templates it generates your database from your code not the other way round. Watch the video and you'll understand - http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Using_SimpleRepository

Comment: Hi Adam - Thanks for helping, I need to use Active Record completely understand how to make it work BUT... Still cannot execute the tt files?  I am using VS2008 (Not Express)?  When I right click on the files there is no 'Run Custom Tool' option?  Only thing I can think of is that this is not MVC but webforms site?  Also its a website, not a project?  Really appreciate your help as I do want to use v3 :)

Comment: If it's a website not a web application project that may well be the cause. Try adding a separate project and dropping the templates in there then reference the project from your website.

Comment: "If your project is a Website rather than a Web Application Project t4 won't work and you won't see 'Run Custom Tool' in the right click menu." 
This should be the first advice for SubSonic 3 newcomers ...