# How to generate database class files with SubSonic 3?

Tags: activerecord, subsonic, subsonic3

I've been using SubSonic (ActiveRecord) for a couple of years. I've been waiting until a few of the bugs in 3.0 were fixed before downloading the newest release and upgrading my few sites that use SubSonic to 3.0. I'm currently using 2.2 on these sites. I'm working on a new site and wanted to use 3.0 to get a grip on the new updates before going back and updating my existing sites to 3.0.

However, I'm stuck and the old SubSonic site with forums and useful help documents seemed to have all changed and there's nothing there that I can find to answer my basic questions.

**How can I generate database class files with SubSonic 3?**

In version 2.x, I used the SubCommander tool integrated with Visual Studio and it just took a click of a menu choice to regenerate all of the class files. Now, there's just a single binary .dll file and no information on how to actually generate my class files.

This question is posed for a new database and new web site, but I have several other existing web sites/databases that I'd like to upgrade. Is there a document on how to transition from SubSonic 2 to SubSonic 3? Preferably, a document that takes into consideration existing implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a document on transitioning from 2 to 3 although I think it'd be a great thing for someone to write. However you should find answers on how to get started from the [docs](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Main_Page) site.
In particular it sounds like you should have a look at:

1. [The 5 minute ActiveRecord demo](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/The_5_Minute_Demo)
2. [Using SubSonic 3 ActiveRecord](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Using_ActiveRecord)
3. [ActiveRecord overview](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/ActiveRecord)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166222/subsonic-3-installation-doesnt-work/1166625#1166625) should also have answers to some of the pitfalls when get started with SubSonic 3 and t4.